# Where to free allocated memory by jni NewByteArray

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a jni function which calls an instance method. This function passes a byte array to the java side as below pseudocode. Do I need to `DeleteLocalRef` and `ReleaseByteArrayElements` in `C` side and what should I do in the `Java` side?

```
// C side
func() {
  while(something) {
    jbyteArray array = NewByteArray();
    // pass c side array as parameter to the java side
    callInstanceMethod(array);
    // delete and relase here?
  }
}

// Java side
method(byte[] array) {
  // delete array??
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to DeleteLocalRef and ReleaseByteArrayElements in C side

Yes, otherwise you may exceed your local reference table in the JNI code, which I believe is only 20 large.

> and what should I do in the Java side?

There isn't anything you can do in the Java side. The calling method still holds a reference while the Java callback is executing.

Comment: Thanks. You mean just DeleteLocalRef or both?

Comment: Only DeleteLocalRef.  You only call ReleaseByteArrayElements if you called GetByteArrayElements.